# how to call a function when I press "ok" on navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()

Tags: javascript, gps

I have this function :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);
```

which get the current gps position from the phone. Now, when I press "Confirm" on my phone, before do a request for retrieve the position, I'd like to call a function (so, not in `foundLocation()`, where the location-data is ready).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="btnConfirm">Confirm</button>

document.getElementById("btnConfirm").onclick = function()
{
  call_your_function();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);
}
```

Comment: ? I mean the button of the popup (alert) that appairs when browser try to retrieve gps; not my own personal button :O

Comment: Hmmm I think you won't be able to control it but I have no experience with it ;)